# HTML5 video: randomly stops playing immediately after pressing play button (black screen)

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have a 5MB filesize 40-second long video that is needed to display with audio and controls available.

What I have right now works 95% of the time's page load but sometimes when I or clients visit the website the video randomly stops playing immediately after pressing the play button (it's either a black screen and you cannot even start the video anymore or it's just looping: play, immediate stop, then hitting play results in the same stop on repeat just to hit the play button again ((i believe it happens not even 1-second passing after hitting play button)) which happens until you refresh the page), then if you press play again - same thing repeats.

I tried multiple solutions, my latest code on this:

```
<video controls=""><source src="https://domain-name.com/videos/1700469332_893.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 

let video = $("video");
            video.onerror = () => {
      console.error(`Error ${video.error.code}; details: ${video.error.message}`);
    }

// play the video as soon as the first frames are cached
    video.oncanplay = () => {
      video.play();
    };

    // or play when the entire video is cached
    video.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      video.play();
    };

        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: unable to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/o12bt8gu/1/ . let us know if any error is shown in the developer console of the browser when the mentioned issue occurs.

Comment: the only issue I get is 8 instances of the same error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received.

But I cannot confirm if it's due to video. It also happens from time to time on my dev console.

Comment: Could you pls provide site URL

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant due to confidential reasons I cannot provide URL. I'm thinking that I need to somehow re-load entire video tag or src after page loads, so if it loads with error it could load again.